# Allow AWS Aurora VPC Cluster to be publicly accessible using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk, aws-aurora-serverless

I have tried configuring the RDS cluster using `cluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFromAnyIpv4();`
but still I am not able to connect to my postgres instance, it keeps timing out.

I've been trying to figure this out from 2 days but still no luck, not sure what to do

Here is the full code for CDK config.

```js
import { CdkWorkshopStack } from "../stacks/cdk-workshop-stack";
import * as rds from "@aws-cdk/aws-rds";
import * as ec2 from "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2";
import { ServerlessCluster } from "@aws-cdk/aws-rds";
import { Duration } from "@aws-cdk/core";

export const createDbInstance = (
  scope: CdkWorkshopStack
): { cluster: ServerlessCluster; dbName: string } => {
  // Create the VPC needed for the Aurora Serverless DB cluster
  const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(scope, "AuroraVPC");

  const dbName = "yt_backup";
  // Create the Serverless Aurora DB cluster; set the engine to Postgres
  const cluster = new rds.ServerlessCluster(scope, "yt_backup_cluster", {
    engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_POSTGRESQL,
    parameterGroup: rds.ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(
      scope,
      "ParameterGroup",
      "default.aurora-postgresql10"
    ),

    defaultDatabaseName: dbName,
    //@ts-ignore
    vpc: vpc,
    //@ts-ignore
    scaling: { autoPause: Duration.minutes(10) }, // Optional. If not set, then instance will pause after 5 minutes
  });
  cluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFromAnyIpv4();

  return { cluster, dbName };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This opens the security group to all connections:

```
cluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFromAnyIpv4();
```

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-rds-readme.html#setting-public-accessibility) (see the link for exactly where you would specified this) would give the database server a public IP, allowing connections from outside the VPC:

```
publiclyAccessible: true,
```

However, you are creating a Serverless cluster, which does not support the publicly accessible feature at this time.

Comment: Is this done by AWS on purpose or is it some design constrain ?

Comment: I don't work for AWS so I can't answer that question. I'm not aware of any public statement they have made on that. Although I imagine it is related to the fact that serverless clusters can have instances constantly being added and removed, so there is no persistent instance to assign a public IP address to.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b) mentions a Serverless Aurora DB is not publicly accessible.
Having a database publicly accessible is a bad idea from a security point of view in my opinion. (and definitely not open to 0.0.0.0/0)

An application inside your VPC should connect to the database and if you need to access the database you can use a [BastionHostLinux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.BastionHostLinux.html) , ssh tunnel or [Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/).

You can switch is an "non serverless" database if you really need to as this is publicly accessible if it's on a public subnet and there is an internet gateway for the VPC.

Comment: Okay but can we access it in our lambdas?

Comment: If it's inside the same VPC, yes, you can.